# Should I keep adplus running?

Tags: .net, crash-dumps, adplus

I know that if I'm suffering from the w3wp.exe process crashing, then I could run adplus to capture a dump just before the crash...

But if I'm not expecting any failures or crashes, should I still leave adplus running in crash mode just in case, on a production environment ?
Does this have any effect on performance ?

Answer (score 0):

[This article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/286350) has a section on when not to use ADPlus.  Lots of C++ exceptions or lots of debug output from the app can cause performance issues.